# How to capture internet connection of an Android app without using Wireshark

Tags: java, android, hook

I'm developing an Android app. The app includes both Java code and native code, and uses some 3rd Java libraries (`.jar` files). Now I want to capture all the hosts/domains that the app connects to.

I can use tools like Wireshark but this requires complex setup and filters in order to avoid interference from other apps.

Another method I'm considering is hooking native functions like `gethostbyname`

```
void* my_handler = NULL;
struct hostent* (*my_gethostbyname)(const char*) = NULL;

void init_hook() {
    my_handler = dlopen("libc.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    my_gethostbyname = (struct hostent* (*)(const char*)) dlsym(my_handler, "gethostbyname");
}

struct hostent* gethostbyname(const char* name) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "HOOK", "name = %s", name);
    return my_gethostbyname(name);
}
```

This code works, however, my questions are:

- Is the function `gethostbyname` the correct one that needs to be hooked?
- Does this hooking work for capturing the connections initiated from Java code and the 3rd `.jar` libraries?
- What is your suggestion?